# Request/Get image og meta tag url from other website

Tags: javascript, image

Im developing a web app that the user can save his favorites websites for later, but I want to put a image from the site automatically, in other words, I want get the image from this tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="www.meusite.com.br/imagem.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800"> /** PIXELS **/
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600"> /** PIXELS **/
```

Sorry for my broken english.